# Is it possible to mix certain data types in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm wondering how to store this kind of data structure into Firebase

[image]

What i have learned so far from Firebase Docs was that if we want to store JSON, we could use Firebase Realtime Database. But, if we want to store Images/Video/Files, we could use Firebase Storage.

The issue is i want to store both kind of data (string, and image). Any idea how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your files in Cloud Storage for Firebase, then store a URL or path to the file in Realtime Database.  It's strongly recommended not to store large amounts of binary data in Realtime Database - that's simply not what it's good for.